# Alguien me puede hacer una pequeña explicación de este codigo

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente codigo de python en el cual tengo que sacar el numero mas grande de la lista sin usar la funcion max
He cogido el codigo de internet pero carece de explicacion por eso me gustaria que alguien me explicase

```
lista = [3, 7, 23, -2, 0, 6]
#Declaramos la variable max que sea igual a 0
max = lista[0]
#No se que hace este bucle exactamente
for lista in lista:
    if lista > max:
        max = lista
print("El máximo es " + str(max))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
max = lista[0]
```

Asigna el valor en el indice **0** del arreglo a la variable max, es decir `max = 3`

```
for elemento in lista:
    if elemento > max:
        max = elemento
```

Itera y verifica si el elemento es mayor que el elemento actual, de ser así iguala la variable.

Ejemplo visual

**Primera iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el primer valor de tu lista, es decir 3
    if elemento > max: # elemento = 3, max = 3, entonces 3 > 3? NO.
        max = elemento # No entra.
```

**Segunda iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el segundo valor de tu lista, es decir 7
    if elemento > max: # elemento = 7, max = 7, entonces 7 > 3? SÍ.
        max = elemento # Entra y reasigna, ahora max vale lo que vale elemento (7)
```

**Tercera iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el tercer valor de tu lista, es decir 23
    if elemento > max: # elemento = 23, max = 7, entonces 23 > 7? SÍ.
        max = elemento # Entra y reasigna, ahora max vale lo que vale elemento (23)
```

**Cuarta iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el cuarto valor de tu lista, es decir -2
    if elemento > max: # elemento = -2, max = 23, entonces -2 > 23? NO.
        max = elemento # No entra.
```

**Quinta iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el quinto valor de tu lista, es decir 0
    if elemento > max: # elemento = 0, max = 23, entonces 0 > 23? NO.
        max = elemento # No entra.
```

**Sexta iteración**

```
for elemento in lista: # Elemento vale el cuarto valor de tu lista, es decir 6
    if elemento > max: # elemento = 6, max = 23, entonces 6 > 23? NO.
        max = elemento # No entra.
```

Ya no hay más iteraciones, sale del `for` y `max` sigue valiendo `23`

NOTAS:

`max = lista[0]` no asigna `max = 0` como dice el comentario, sino al indice 0 de tu lista

Aunque el código funciona bien, no uses el mismo nombre de la variable en el for, es decir si tu `list` se llama `lista` en el for no hagas esto `for lista in lista` ya que es confuso y te puede traer problemas al volver a usar `lista` es por ello que en el ejemplo cambié el nombre a `elemento`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha servido mucho <3